# jQuery Datepicker Expiration date

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, datepicker

I am using jQuery UI's Datepicker plugin. When the user logs in, I need to display an error message once the Expiration Date becomes past due. I tried adding the if statement below, but it isn't working. Any ideas?

```
    $("#expDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: 0
    });

   if (Date.parse(expDate) < jQuery.now()) {
      $("#expDate").addClass("error");// . for class  expDate
  }
```

Comment: So what's in `expDate` variable?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. It's a date that's picked when the form is first filled out & submitted.

Comment: Is the code inside `if` statement executing? Is `error` class being added?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to add the jquery selector to the expDate?

Try using:

```
if (Date.parse($('#expDate')) < jQuery.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

Expire date validation using jQuery

Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
```

application.js

```
//= require datapicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js
```

application.css.scss

```
*= require datapicker/datepicker3.css
```

application.js:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: "yy-mm-dd",
        startDate: new Date('2019-1-1'), 
        endDate: new Date('2025-12-31')
      });
    };

});
```